# Passing data from one VC to another and rendering inside table view

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to render a table view using an array of arrays. This 'data' array is initialising a series of variables, which get populated via a segue from the previous screen to this screen.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> 'cannot use instance *var* within property initialiser; property
> initialiser before 'self' is available'

Each of the variables will then be used to render the result passed from the previous screen to this one, but obviously not working due to the above error.

The variables do get passed across, I just can't place them inside this data array.

How can I refactor my code so that this error goes away, and I can access the values by using indexPath.row?

Here's my code:

```
class SingleAccountViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var balance: String?
    var borrowed: String?
    var interestRate: String?
    var monthlyPayment: String?
    var paymentDate: String?
    
    var data = [
        ["Balance", balance],
        ["Borrowed", borrowed],
        ["Interest Rate", interestRate],
        ["Monthly Payment", monthlyPayment],
        ["Payment Date", paymentDate]
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SingleAccountTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SingleAccountCell")
        
    }

}

extension SingleAccountViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let row = data[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleAccountCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleAccountTableViewCell
        
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
var data = [String:String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 data = [
        ["Balance", balance],
        ["Borrowed", borrowed],
        ["Interest Rate", interestRate],
        ["Monthly Payment", monthlyPayment],
        ["Payment Date", paymentDate]
     ] 
}
```

BTW this is not an OOP way you need to create a model and pass it

Comment: How would you recommend converting it into a model?

Comment: @JonNicholson: I would create a struct with balance, borrowed, interestRate, monthlyPayment and paymentDate properties (the model), then create instances of struct and fill the data array with these instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 class SingleAccountTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText:UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var balance: String?
    var borrowed: String?
    var interestRate: String?
    var monthlyPayment: String?
    var paymentDate: String?
    
    var data = [[String:String?]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        data = [
            ["Balance": balance],
            ["Borrowed":borrowed],
            ["Interest Rate": interestRate],
            ["Monthly Payment": monthlyPayment],
            ["Payment Date":paymentDate]
        ]
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SingleAccountTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SingleAccountCell")
        
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleAccountCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleAccountTableViewCell
        if data.count > indexPath.row{
            let row = data[indexPath.row]
            if let key = row.keys.first, let  val = row[key] as? String{
                cell.lblText.text = val
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```